# Loop violating Primary Key Value

Tags: function, postgresql, for-loop, primary-key

I have a part of my function mentioned below.
When I execute the function I get an error saying primary key violation for alarm_id

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT exception_sub_type) INTO v_count FROM mdas.alarm_configuration;

IF v_count > 0 THEN

FOR i IN 1..v_count
LOOP

SELECT ((MAX(alarm_id))+1) INTO v_alarm_id FROM mdas.alarm_configuration;

RAISE NOTICE 'ALARM ID (%)',v_alarm_id;

INSERT INTO mdas.alarm_configuration
    (alarm_id,
     exception_sub_type,
     exception_type,
     from_range,
     groups,
     priority,
     sub_group,
     to_range,
     org_unit_id,
     status)

SELECT DISTINCT ON(exception_sub_type) v_alarm_id,
exception_sub_type,
exception_type,
from_range,
v_group_name,
priority,
v_subgroup_name,
to_range,
v_org_unit_id,
status
FROM mdas.alarm_configuration 
WHERE groups = v_group_name AND mdas.alarm_configuration.org_unit_id = v_org_unit_id;

END LOOP;   

END IF;
```

Note: This is only a part of the function. The function has three arguments v_org_unit_id, v_group_name and v_subgroup_name. My primary key is on alarm_id, which I want to increment by 1 and insert based on the MAX which is available in the table.

Comment: why you not use **serial** data type for alarm_id?

Comment: Don't use `max(alarm_id)` to generate a PK value. It is slow, not scalable and what's worse: it's plain incorrect in a multi-user environment. Use a sequence (or serial as Ilesh suggested). And the `distinct on()` does not seem to make any sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your environment, when more than two client call the function at the same time, they will see the same alarm_id, so raise unique violated.
for exp :

```
SESSION A : 
select max(id) into v_id from test;
insert into test values (v_id);
.. not end else.

SESSION B : 
select max(id) into v_id from test;   -- this v_id will same as session a.
insert into test values (v_id);

and then session A commit;
SESSION B will raise error.
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(?) already exists.
```

You can use PostgreSQL serial deal this problem.
LIKE :

```
digoal=# create table test (id serial primary key, other_cols type ...);
CREATE TABLE
```

and not need to use max(id), you only need type other columns's values.
like

```
insert into test (other_cols,...) values (...);
```